# "superimpose" the count table and percentage table in R

Tags: r, frequency

The script below illustrate my question:

```
library(reshape2)

set.seed(1)
dummy.df <- data.frame(var_a=sample(letters[1:5],200,replace=TRUE),
                       var_b=sample(1:5,200,replace=TRUE),
                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

temp1 <- addmargins(table(dummy.df[,c("var_a","var_b")]),1)
temp2 <- formatC(addmargins(prop.table(table(dummy.df[,c("var_a","var_b")]),2),1)*100,digits=2,format="f")

temp1.melt <- melt(temp1,id.vars="var_a")
temp2.melt <- melt(temp2,id.vars="var_a")

temp.output <- merge(temp1.melt,temp2.melt,by=c("var_a","var_b"))
temp.output[,"value"] <- paste(temp.output[,"value.x"]," (",temp.output[,"value.y"],"%)",sep="")
temp.output[,"var_a"] <- factor(temp.output[,"var_a"],levels=c("a","b","c","d","e","Sum"))
temp.output <- dcast(temp.output,formula=var_a~var_b,value.var="value")
```

One of my usual work in office is to create tables listing the frequency between different variables, usually I will include the percentage (row/column percentage) in the table also.

Before I know the function `addmargins`, `prop.table` and `as.data.frame.matrix`, I use lots of `melt` and `dcast` from `reshape2` package to do the trick (i.e. convert the table to dataframe, `melt` it, do the appropriate division to give the percentage, then `dcast` it). Now I know using the three new learnt function can save me lots of codes.

Now I wonder if this can be moving one step ahead, without using the script I provided above, and to create a table with row/column percentage present next to the actual count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of columns is N then this takes the two table and rearranges. Since you have figured out the renaming of columns I will not bore you with that:

```
 temp12 <- cbind(temp1, temp2)
stopifnot( ncol(temp1) == ncol(temp2))
data.frame( var_a=rownames(temp1), temp12[ ,c(t(matrix(1:10, 5,2))) ] )
#----- 
    var_a X1   X1.1 X2   X2.1 X3   X3.1 X4   X4.1 X5   X5.1
a       a  7  15.22  9  18.75  7  17.07  4  14.29  2   5.41
b       b 13  28.26 12  25.00  6  14.63  5  17.86  9  24.32
c       c  9  19.57  9  18.75  9  21.95  3  10.71 13  35.14
d       d  9  19.57  9  18.75  8  19.51 12  42.86 10  27.03
e       e  8  17.39  9  18.75 11  26.83  4  14.29  3   8.11
Sum   Sum 46 100.00 48 100.00 41 100.00 28 100.00 37 100.00
```

(You could use the same matrix transpose trick to choose from two appended vectors of constructed column names.)

Comment: yea, it is close, but you doubled the number of columns minus one in the tables

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you referring to the fact that the first column is not the group labels? If so, it's dealt with.

Comment: @DWin might I suggest to replace `matrix(1:10, 5,2)` by `matrix(seq(1,ncol(temp1)*2), ncol(temp1),2)` ...

Comment: @DWin, what I mean is that my table was originally consist of 6 columns, but now your output gives 11 columns, if I export it to excel and give borders, it will look different from my original output

Comment: I was trying to mimic the output you offered with temp.output ... which had 11 columns. Feel free to edit your question to define explicitly what you want. My mind-reader is not working at the moment.